# File upload to SharePoint online library using Microsoft.Graph version 5

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, .net-7.0

I have upgraded the graph package to version 5.0.  What are the changes required for the below code used to upload file to SharePoint online library.

Framework: Dot Net 7

```
        
public async Task<string> SharePointUploadFileAsync(
    string site, string libraryId, IFormFile file, string fileName){

       string newFileId = string.Empty;

     var targetFolder = graphClient.Sites[site]
               .Lists[libraryId]
               .Drive.Root;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) //this keeps the stream open
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var buf2 = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Read(buf2, 0, buf2.Length);

            ms.Position = 0;
            var uploadedItem = await targetFolder
                  .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                  .Content
                  .Request()
                  .PutAsync<DriveItem>(ms);

        newFileId = uploadedItem.Id;

            ms.Dispose();
        }

     return newFileId
}
```

Upgraded graph package to version 5.0

Comment: I noticed `.Content.Request()PutAsync` in your code, and in v5 version SDK, there seems to be missing `.Request()` anymore. like [the sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet#4-make-requests-to-the-graph). and the migration [guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#removal-of-request-from-the-fluent-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue and ended with this code for `Microsoft.Graph v5.0.0` (preview and rc). I haven't tested it yet.

```
public async Task<string> SharePointUploadFileAsync(
string site, string libraryId, IFormFile file, string fileName)
{

    string newFileId = string.Empty;

    // cannot access root through Sites[site].Lists[libraryId].Drive
    var drive = await _client.Sites[site].Lists[libraryId].Drive.GetAsync();

    // use drive id from previous call and access root through Drives[]
    var targetFolder = _client.Drives[drive.Id].Root;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) //this keeps the stream open
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var buf2 = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(buf2, 0, buf2.Length);

        ms.Position = 0;

        // it doesn't return driveItem but I expect that it will create a new driveItem
        // I didn't find any Post method on targetFolder.ItemWithPath(fileName)
        await targetFolder
                  .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                  .Content
                  .PutAsync(ms);
        
        // get drive id
        var uploadedItem = await targetFolder.ItemWithPath(fileName).GetAsync();

        newFileId = uploadedItem.Id;

        ms.Dispose();
    }

    return newFileId;
}
```

Discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1290) about preview v5